# Ubuntu boots from USB but get GRUB rescue after installation

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I can boot Ubuntu from USB, but when I took the USB stick out of the laptop and booted again, I got an error saying

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what are the os's did you installed?

Comment: Only Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 on your hard disk,and your usb stick consits of ubuntu installation files.is that correct?

Comment: Yes, You are correct. But on the usb stick are some files too, that are not from the instalation files, like a song or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Boot into Ubuntu using Ubuntu live usb stick, choose `Try Ubuntu`, then connect to the internet and type the following commands in terminal to install **boot-repair**.

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
  ```
- Click **Recommended Repair**

Reboot and you should get the GRUB menu with access to Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't boot into ubuntu. When I press F10 it shows me the same text.

Comment: boot into ubuntu live disk means,boot the ubuntu installation usb stick by changing the boot order to usb in bios.

Comment: yes. My mistake. Sorry. It's allright now, thank you.